# PHP don't respond after imagedestroy

Tags: php

While developing I faced a problem. After calling imagedestroy my script won't execute some PHP nor HTML.

When I delete the header it execute the PHP / HTML after the imagedestroy, but I need that header in my script. So my question is; how can a PHP header affect the PHP script.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/png;'); 


$im = @imagecreatefrompng('ticket.png') or die("Cannot select the correct image. Please contact the webmaster."); 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0,0,0); 

/*
$name = $_GET['name'];
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$time = $_GET['time'];
$date = $_GET['date'];
$agent = $_GET['agent'];
$sno = $_GET['sno'];
$flightno = $_GET['flightno'];
$boardingtime = $_GET['boardingtime'];
$gate = $_GET['gate'];
$seat = $_GET['seat'];
*/

$name = $_POST['name'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$agent = $_POST['agent'];
$sno = rand(101, 199);
$flightno = $_POST['flightno'];
$boardingtime = $_POST['boardingtime'];
$gate = $_POST['gate'];
$seat = $_POST['seat'];

$text_name = "$name"; 
$text_from = "$from";
$text_to = "$to";
$text_time = "$time";
$text_date = "$date";
$text_agent = "$agent";
$text_sno = "$sno";
$text_flightno = "$flightno";
$text_boardingtime = "$boardingtime";
$text_gate = "$gate";
$text_seat = "$seat";

$font = 'font.ttf';

#Basis in het midden.
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 119, 168, $text_color, $font, $text_name);
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 119, 184, $text_color, $font, $text_from);
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 100, 201, $text_color, $font, $text_to);
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 185, 235, $text_color, $font, $text_time);
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 498, 167, $text_color, $font, $text_date);
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 509, 184, $text_color, $font, $text_agent);
imagettftext($im, 21, 0, 544, 260, $text_color, $font, $text_sno);

#Top
imagettftext($im, 14, 0, 97, 85, $text_color, $font, $text_flightno);
imagettftext($im, 14, 0, 289, 85, $text_color, $font, $text_boardingtime);
imagettftext($im, 14, 0, 398, 85, $text_color, $font, $text_gate);
imagettftext($im, 14, 0, 486, 85, $text_color, $font, $text_seat);

$rand = rand(0, 3498);
imagepng($im);
imagepng($im, 'images/' . $rand . '.png'); 
imagedestroy($im);

echo 'This does not display';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the issue is that the browser doesn't know how to handle the data it's receiving. According to the docs, if you do not supply a path to `imagepng()` it will output the data to the browser. If you have not specified the correct headers, it should output as text. If you have, it should output as an image. If you provide the headers that tell the browser to treat it as an image, the image parser will probably discard the extra characters 'This does not display' that are appended to the end of the image data.

Try getting rid of `imagepng($im)` and watch as it saves the image then outputs 'This does not display'.

https://www.php.net/imagepng

Comment: Well, the image does display but the echo that I try to execute after won't work. WHen I remove the imagepng($im) the 'This does not display' still don't work.

Comment: In fact, clearly you did not try it without imagepng($im), because I just did and it works fine.

Comment: error_reporting does not display anything, I don't see why it works at you, because it still doesn't at me.